# after a click event at javascript , the browser execute the code from the top of the page(it initialize the variables ) like it just opened.?

Tags: javascript, html

the problem is after an onclick that gets a form inputs and place it to an array.** when clicking on a button the browser execute the file from scratch and doesnt save anything  that happend at the event.  meaning it process the code from the start of the program.**
i am really lost here if someone could help i would be very grateful
also the console.log eraised
thank you *very* much

```
<form>
      <h2>add contact</h2>
      <label><span>enter name</span> <input type="text" name="form_name" id="form_name" required></label>
      <label><span>enter phone format "04-8888888"</span><input type="tel" name="form_tel" id="form_tel"
          placeholder="04-8888888" pattern="[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{7}" required></label>
      <label><span>enter mail</span><input type="email" id="form_mail" name="form_mail" placeholder="aaa@gmail.com"
          required></label>
      <textarea id="form_text" name="form_text" rows="5" placeholder="free text"></textarea>
      <fieldset><button id="form_submit" name="form_submit">submit</button><button id="form_out"
          name="form_out">clear</button></fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>
```

listener to add
const add = document.querySelector(".add_contact");
add.addEventListener("click", show_form);

function add_new_contact(e) {

console.log(arr_of_contacts);
let b = true;
for (let i of arr

```js
function add_new_contact(e) {
  //add contact if name is not at the array
  console.log(arr_of_contacts);
  let b = true;
  for (let i of arr_of_contacts) {
    console.log(arr_of_contacts);
    if (document.querySelector("#form_name").value === i.name) {
      b = false;
      alert("same name");
    }
  }
  console.log("s");
  if (b) {
    let new_contact = new contact(
      e.target.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("#form_name").value,

      e.target.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("#form_mail").value,
      e.target.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("#form_text").value,
      e.target.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("#form_tel").value
    );
    console.log(new_contact);
    arr_of_contacts.push(new_contact);
    alert(arr_of_contacts[arr_of_contacts.length - 1].name);
    console.log(arr_of_contacts);

    display_contacts_name_phone();
  }
```

> inside the js function the array get the values he should get but then he just forget and also the console.log eraised

Comment: There's no element with the class of `add_contact` in the markup.

Comment: Without seeing the markup of the `.add_contact` element, I'd guess, that it's a button element without type attribute. In a form that is a submitter element, and your form is submitted, and a new page is returned by the server, which actually is the current page, as the `form` doesn't have `action` attribute.

Comment: thank you very much this was the problem. im much fan of you(: